# how does str.length() work to calculate string length()?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Suppose I create a string of size `n` initially.

Can I change its `length()` by any method? (since it is just an array of characters, so `n` must be an upper limit of string) Is there any way of reducing `str.length()` result?

If so, then how does `str.length()` calculate length? If it calculates by finding `'\0'`, then if I change any in between character to `'\0'`, can `n` be reduced?

Comment: [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) can do what you want (if I understood what you are asking).

Comment: `std::string` is not just an array of characters.

Comment: What is `str`??

Comment: You need to show your actual code you are worried about. The answers you seek depend on the actual type `str` is declared as. We are *assuming* `std::string`.

Comment: `std::string` is almost the same as `std::vector<char>`. How does the vector know its length, in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, I'm not sure what you are exactly asking, but it depends on implementation. There are many kinds of `string`. With regard to  `'\0'`, the string length can be got by counting the letter until it meets `'\0'`. Putting this null character to earlier position will reduce `str.length()`, but it's not very recommended.

For question 2, yes it's true. Moreover, if you *remove* `'\0'`, the string will not be able to function as a string. That's why we need one more space to store the string than it's original length, to store null character.

Comment: It's not clear, but it appears the OP is referring to `std::string` specifically.

Comment: If it is so, then Why http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/ this articles shows the complexity as constant? Though it traces full string

Comment: `std:string` contains it's own size. Everytime the string is created or modified, the size is also changed. It calculates it's size in advance, so no matter how long the string is, it can remain constant time. As I said, there are many implementations of `string`. `std:string` is not just an array of characters, as the comment above says.

Comment: @MyBug18: std::basic_string is *explicitly* allowed to contain embedded zero bytes, so "counting until `'\0'`" is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are referring to `std::string`, as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (definition: `std::basic_string<char>`):

> If so, then how does str.length() calculate length? If it calculates by finding '\0', then if I change any in between character to '\0', can n be reduced?

The C++ standard does not prescribe the implementation details of `std::string`, only it`s behavior/interface, but I guess all implementations are generally as follows:

You have a class containing a pointer to the corresponding memory that is needed for your string and 2 integers. The integers store the actual length of your string and the size of the allocated memory. So when you call `str.length()`, it just looks up the stored number in constant time. So there is no calculation. Therefore, you also can't change its size by inserting a `\0`. In fact, by storing the size explicitly, you don't need the `\0` at all.

> Can I change its length() by any method?
>   Is there any way of reducing str.length() result?

There exists a specific `resize` method. However, you can also use several other methods to modify it's length, for example, `insert`, `append`, `clear` and some others. Just look into the linked documentation. The class itself takes care of the memory allocations to store the result of those operations. You can also get the size of the underlying memory with the `capacity` method. If you apply some operations on your string, you will notice, that the value returned by `capacity` might be equal to `length`, but it can also be higher. If you reduce the length of your string, most implementations won't reallocate the underlying memory.